# Antd steps form validation in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

i have been trying to create form validation in steps with Antd, but I am struggling with the validation part. My goal is that i cannot click next if fields are not filled correctly. As i understand, i have to make form submit every time I click next, but since I am a beginner i don't know how to do it with nested components. Profile component is nested inside third step. Can you please help me?

```
const { Step } = Steps;

const steps = [
    {
        title: 'First',
        content: 'First-content',
    },
    {
        title: 'Second',
        content: 'Second-content',
    },
    {
        title: 'third',
        content: <Profile/>,
    },
    {
        title: 'last',
        content: 'Third',
    },
];

const ListingSteps = () => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
    const onChange = current =>{
        setCurrent(current)
    }
 const next = () => {
        setCurrent(current + 1);
    };

    const prev = () => {
        setCurrent(current - 1);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Steps current={current} onChange={onChange}>
                {steps.map(item => (
                    <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
                ))}
            </Steps>
            <div className="steps-content">{steps[current].content}</div>
            <div className="steps-action">
                {current < steps.length - 1 && (
                    <Button type="primary" onClick={() => next()}>
                        Next
                    </Button>
                )}
                {current === steps.length - 1 && (
                    <Button type="primary" onClick={() => message.success('Processing complete!')}>
                        Done
                    </Button>
                )}
                {current > 0 && (
                    <Button style={{ margin: '0 8px' }} onClick={() => prev()} >
                        Previous
                    </Button>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
```

PROFILE

```
function Profile() {
    
    return(
        <>
           <Form name="profile" >
                            <Form.Item  name="name" label='Name' rules={[{required:true, message:'Please enter your name' }]}>
                                <Input/>
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item name="surname" label='Surname' rules={[{required:true, message:'Please enter your name' }]}>
                                <Input/>
                            </Form.Item>
           </Form>
        </>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **form.validateFields()**.
When you click on Next button, you can check the all the required fields for current Step by passing all the fields `name` in validateFields.
For example, in your Profile Component, you have two Fields: `name` & `Surname`
You can validate the fields by:

```
const onNext = async () => {
        try {
            await form.validateFields(['name', 'surname']);
            setCurrent((prev)=>prev + 1);
        } catch {}
    };
```

Add one more key in each object of step list and pass an array of form field name in for that Step component.

```
const steps = [
    {
        title: 'third',
        content: <Profile/>,
        fields: ['name', 'surname']
    },
    ....
];
```

Now you can validate each step component by getting each step fields from steps array.

```
await form.validateFields(steps[current].fields);
```

Check the FormInstance API:
https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance